# How do I get a ExtJS 4.1.X Bar Chart with a single bar to show that bar's label properly?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, ria

If you try the live code example in the documentation at:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Bar

More than one label looks beautiful:

[image: Bar Chart with Two Labels]

```
data: [
    { 'name': 'metric one',  'data':5 },
    { 'name': 'metric two',  'data':27 }
]
```

However as soon as you reduce the dataset down to one label, the output looks horrible(notice the label for the bar appears half outside the top of the chart area, instead of vertically aligned with the bar it is to label):

[image: Bar Chart with One Label]

Is this a bug in ExtJS? How do I work around this?  Exact ExtJS code that produces this output:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    fields: ['name', 'data'],
    data: [
        { 'name': 'metric one',  'data':5 }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    animate: true,
    store: store,
    axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['data'],
        label: {
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
        },
        title: 'Sample Values',
        grid: true,
        minimum: 0
    }, {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['name'],
        title: 'Sample Metrics'
    }],
    series: [{
        type: 'bar',
        axis: 'bottom',
        highlight: true,
        tips: {
          trackMouse: true,
          width: 140,
          height: 28,
          renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
            this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('data') + ' views');
          }
        },
        label: {
            display: 'insideEnd',
            field: 'data',
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0'),
            orientation: 'horizontal',
            color: '#333',
            'text-anchor': 'middle'
        },
        xField: 'name',
        yField: 'data'
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to replace

```
axisRange = to - from,
```

on line *383* of *Axis.js* in ExtJS with

```
axisRange = to - from == 0 ? 1 : to - from,
```

to prevent a divide by zero being assigned to the `y` coordinate of the
axis label.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the default rendering does look weird when it is just one record.
It can be fixed or worked around though.

In concept, override the series renderer to fix the height and y point in case of single record -

```
renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
    if (store.getCount() == 1) {
        attr.height = 80;
        attr.y = 75;
    }
    return attr;
}
```

[image]

You can make changes to the actual overridden values (`attr.height and attr.y`) to suit your visual needs.

Here is your example modified to look close to what you would expect.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    fields: ['name', 'data'],
    data: [
        {'name': 'metric one','data': 5}
        //,{'name': 'metric two','data': 7}
    ]
});


Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    animate: true,
    store: store,
    axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['data'],
        label: {
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
        },
        title: 'Sample Values',
        grid: true,
        minimum: 0},
    {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['name'],
        title: 'Sample Metrics'}],
    series: [{
        type: 'bar',
        axis: 'bottom',

        highlight: true,
        tips: {
            trackMouse: true,
            width: 140,
            height: 28,
            renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + storeItem.get('data') + ' views');
            }
        },
        label: {
            display: 'insideEnd',
            field: 'data',
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0'),
            orientation: 'horizontal',
            color: '#333',
            'text-anchor': 'middle'
        },
        xField: 'name',
        yField: 'data',
        renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
            if (store.getCount() == 1) {
                attr.height = 80;
                attr.y = 75;
            }
            return attr;

        }}]
});​
```

Comment: You example moves the bar, not the label.  The label is still off in heaven.  It has given me hope though.

Comment: On closer inspection I can see that the y attribute is getting set to NaN on the text tag that wraps the label... is there a way to manually override the calculation that results in that?

Answer (score 0):

If it seems right, just change the height to 150 from 300 :

```
Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 500,
    height: 150,
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating to ExtJS 4.2 should fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in one bar, it is because of the range so if you have a wide range and one bar the labels will not repeat, it is great to hear that it is fixed in version 4.2 please confirm this if you try it.